# Getting the unconnected network drives

Tags: networking, powershell

If I query the drives right after PC startup, I get a list without network drives:

```
PS C:\Users\thomas> get-psdrive

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                               CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                               ---------------
Alias                                  Alias
C                 211,64         32,50 FileSystem    C:\                                                  Users\thomas
Cert                                   Certificate   \
Env                                    Environment
Function                               Function
HKCU                                   Registry      HKEY_CURRENT_USER
HKLM                                   Registry      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Variable                               Variable
WSMan                                  WSMan
```

Later, when the network drives are connected, the list is longer (note the W: drive):

```
PS C:\Users\thomas> get-psdrive

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                               CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                               ---------------
Alias                                  Alias
C                 211,73         32,41 FileSystem    C:\                                                  Users\thomas
Cert                                   Certificate   \
Env                                    Environment
Function                               Function
HKCU                                   Registry      HKEY_CURRENT_USER
HKLM                                   Registry      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Variable                               Variable
W                  61,51        279,95 FileSystem    \\server\files
WSMan
```

The command `net use` lists those network drives, even if not connected. What is the Powershell equivalent of `net use`?

I've tried looking up functions in Powershell ISE for the filter `get*net*` and `get*drive*` but I was unable to find a function that would suit my needs.

After the suggestions of @MrPowerUser, I tried

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_mappedlogicaldisk | select deviceid
```

and

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * From Win32_LogicalDisk Where DriveType = 4"
```

But this results in the connected drives only. I'm looking for the ones that are not connected.

Comment: Take a look at this: `Get-WmiObject -Class win32_mappedlogicaldisk | select deviceid`

Comment: @MrPowerUser: thanks for the hint. The exact command only lists the drives that are connected. I'm looking for the non-connected ones.

Comment: Can I ask for what purpose you need the unconnected drives?

Comment: @SimonS: a) I want to try a reconnect and if it still does not connect b) check if the network path is correct (server name, path etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a result with how Windows functions.  That is to say, this behavior is by design.

The drives don't exist yet because Windows hasn't re-mapped them yet.  It doesn't do that immediately because the OS gives the user control before logon has actually finished.  This is a trade off between required functionality and time to usability.  About the best you could do is enumerate the drives at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network` or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2` which should include most network mapped drives.  However, those mapped by group policy preferences or that aren't mapped persistently may not be present in the registry at all.

You *may* be able to prevent this behavior by [disabling Fast Logon Optimization by using Group Policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg486839.aspx) to force Windows to wait for the network at logon, or the ["Run logon scripts synchronously" feature to force](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc975925(v=technet.10)) to force the system to run all scripts before starting Explorer.  I'm not sure how the second one interacts with GP Preferences.  However, either way there are some pretty significant side effects, such as slower logon or possible issues with not being able to logon if your computer is not connected to the network (e.g., a laptop offsite).  You're not speeding anything up here.  You're just force delaying logon so that more stuff finishes before Windows lets the user do anything.

If you really need to run a script at logon which accesses a network share, you should use the UNC path and not the network drive.  It should be noted that most PowerShell cmdlets support UNC paths.

If you need to verify that a mapped drive exists, you just need to wait.

> What is the Powershell equivalent of `net use`?

`Get-PSDrive` and `New-PSDrive`.